# Kohana 3.2 ORM - a sample of the unique values

Tags: orm, kohana-3.2

Here is my query:

```
 $comment = ORM::factory('comment')
                  ->where('status', '=', 1)
                  ->find_all();
```

field = `user_id`

How do I chose to only one of each comments in `user_id`?

The following:

```
$comment = ORM::factory('comment')
                  ->distinct('user_id')
                  ->where('status', '=', 1)
                  ->find_all();
```

Displays everything in the database!

Comment: What do you want to do? 1. Display the most recent comment for every user_id. 2. Select a specific comment for a single user_id. 3. Want to know how to pass parameters into the model to select a specific record.

Answer (score 0):

You code should be more like this..

```
$comment = ORM::factory('comment')
                  ->where('status', '=', 1)
                  ->group_by('user_id')
                  ->find_all();
```

Check the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#group_by) for more info.